# KDB How to cause infinite loop without recursion

Tags: kdb

Is there an expression that causes an infinite loop in KDB?

This is without using loops or recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A statement including a scan or over adverb can get you stuck in an infinite loop.  Something like:

```
{sqrt x}\[{x>0};100]
```

this will continually take the square root of the previous output (with an initial input of 100) until the answer no longer satisfies x>0.  So the first argument is effectively a while, even though we don't use the while key word.  Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean without using `while` loops etc. You should look into the behavior of `over` and `scan` when the function that is applied is monadic. This behavior is detailed in the kx wiki [iteration with over](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#over)